# Laravel Distinct when 2 columns in returned data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to show a list of addresses using Laravel (8) for  datatable.

My Laravel fluent is:

```
$ad = DB::connection('ALocks')->table('job')
      ->distinct()
      ->orderBy('address')
      ->select(['address as address','id as id'])
      ->get();
```

But it returns all.

I have tried

```
$ad = DB::connection('ALocks')->table('job')
      ->distinct('address')
      ->orderBy('address')
      ->select(['address as address','id as id'])
      ->get();
```

but this returns all the data.

I only want the address to be distinct not both the address and id.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `JOB::all()->pluck('address');` or `JOB::all()->pluck('address')->where('id','=',$id);` and you can pass the id here.

Comment: the ID is just for me to use in the next part. I just want it available in the returned data with the address distinct

Comment: you could try to group by the address

Comment: Then you can use `JOB::all()->pluck('address')` Eloquent is the best way to write a query in laravel.

Comment: @HassaanAli there is no reason to return all the results to pluck a column when the builder itself has a `pluck` method ... and eloquent uses query builder so its all query builder `:)`